# Android facebook messenger raw contact intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts, android-facebook, facebook-messenger

Well, i'm getting RawContacts for a contact from ContactProvider.
Viber, Whatsapp, Skype, Telegram, etc are launching well with

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" + rawContactId);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

But when it comes to Facebook Messenger's RawContacts something goes wrong

> E/msgr(:):AbstractIntentHandlerActivity: Future failed for
>   intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/21839 flg=0x10800000
>   cmp=com.facebook.orca/com.facebook.messenger.intents.IntentHandlerActivity
>   }. Waiting for result: false.

Does anybody know why standard contact-view Intent doesn't work well and is there elegant solution for this situation?

Standard Android Contacts application handles this situation well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to standard Android Contacts application source code, mimetype should be passed to Intent.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" + rawContactId);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(uri, rawContactMimetype);
```

And facebook messengers starts correctly